# Script Panel was inactive during page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have a $.ajaxSubmit function and it is working fine with other browsers. I have included all necessary jquery plugins. In Firefox (21.0) also works but after refreshing the page many times. On first page load does not work in Firefox but works fine in other Chrome/IE ...

I go to Firebug and it in Script tab it says `Script Panel was inactive during page load`. And when I press `Reload` everything works fine.

How can I load the Script on first page load ? Thanks.

I have lots of javascript codes in JSP file, more than 2000 lines of code. Does it create the problem ?